# past simple and continuous

Tags: past-tense, past-simple, past-continuous

> "Nero played music while Rome was burning."

I just copied it from one English workbook for primary school. If it was **watched, saw**... I would take it as correct. This really bothers me, I cannot think of any grammar rule that this sentence makes correct, perhaps I am wrong.

I am confused since the book is for 7th graders and they are just about to learn the basic form like...a simple somehow 'interrupts' or 'stops' a long action in continuous form ( just basic like she broke her arm while she was skiing) it never occurred to me it actually is present participle....

It is why I mention see and watch as in 'I saw them playing, running..)

I still cannot grasp Nero one since there must be some other ways it to be described...yes that lack of connection...

Wouldn't it be easier to say that he played/was playing while watching the burning Rome?

Comment: Hello, Jenny. ''Petro helped with the fire-fighting while Rome was burning''.  You can use past simple alongside the past continuous. Perhaps you're worried about the apparent lack of connection between a city burning and a ruler playing music. "The citizens of Istria went about their normal business while Rome was burning" is equally grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

The specific phrase refers the a story that Emporer Nero played music instead of organising the firefighters in the [great fire of Rome.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Fire_of_Rome)

The grammar is correct. The past tense for the action in the past:

> Nero played music.

and a "while" phrase using a continuous tense is typical and correct

> while Rome was burning.

This tells us when Nero played music, and suggests that the fire was burning for a period of time.  This is the past continuous form of the verb "burn"

Burn is a verb that can have a two senses, one with and one without an object:

> I burn the paper
>
> The paper burns

Compare this to

> I close the door
>
> The door closes.

So it is correct to say "Rome was burning", to mean "Rome was on fire."

Answer (score 0):

First: "was burning" in this context is [**middle-voice**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_(grammar)#Middle) = passive voice using active voice.

Second, we have 2 actions:

- was burning = needs to be in continuous mode, because it denotes an ongoing, longer  activity;
- played (music) = it is a (rather short) action (event) which happened during the long(er) activity (the burning)

Answer (score -3):

In that sentence **burning** is not a verb (one of the telltale signs is that there is no object), and so that clause is not a past continuous clause but rather a past simple clause where the word burning is a present participle(a type of adjective) and the verb is **was**.

as in: He is **annoying**.

**annoying** is not a verb, it is an adjective, a predicate nominative not an object.

it might be more obvious in: the **burning** man struggled for his life.

also from [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/burning):

> [bur-ning]
>
> adjective
>
> 1. aflame; on fire.
> 2. very hot; simmering: The water was burning.
> 3. very bright; glowing: She wore a burning red bathing suit.

Comment: 'Burning' is the present participle here; intransitive verbs (more accurately, verbs used intransitively) have no objects. A better check is 'while Rome was burning to the ground'.

Comment: I think the dictionary is quite clear on this case.
Burning is synonymous to aflame.
Example 2 clearly shows that it is the same structure and burning is an adjective there.
a better check is : He is happy to a fault; does that mean happy is a verb ?

Comment: Think about 'Rome burned to the ground while Nero was playing.' (Just the construction, not the time he'd have to keep fiddling.) 'Playing', like 'burning' in OP's example, is a verb-form.

Comment: I understand it now, that object part :D I am not allowed to thank, nevertheless I will, Big thank you Mr Ashworth. x

Comment: burning man is not the same as X was burning.